# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to extract all the brand names from https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/.
Below is the code for mobiles_spiders.py file

```
class MobilesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mobiles"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/',
           
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'mobiles-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.xpath(str.encode('.//div[has-class("all-brands-block-desc-brand")]/text()').get()))
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

but the code is giving me error as
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'
i need suggestion as to what function i need to use instead of get() for extracting all the div elements that contains brand name.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a ) at the wrong place, you probably want to call .get() on the xpath, not the encode. Also, why would you need encode in the first place, doesn't xpath take strings?

Comment: XPath doesn't take strings for python 3.x,the argument needs to be passed as bytes and not strings.

Comment: For OP. See here for docs. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING. UTF-8 encoding is the default for scrapy except for JSON. If your output is JSON you have set FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING to UTF-8 explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help you.

```
import scrapy
    
class MobilesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mobiles"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/',

        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'mobiles-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.xpath('.//div[has-class("all-brands-block-desc-brand")]/text()').get().encode('utf-8'))
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: Scrapy uses UTF-8 for everything except JSON outputs. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING
So there's no need for encode('utf-8') here.